# React Native Navigator didfocus event listener

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-redux

I am having a very weird issue with react native navigator.

I have a `ScrollableTabView` that has multiple navigators, on some scenes of a specific navigator, i want to hide the bottom navigation.

I tried using the onFocus event for navigator to get the current scene details, turned out it was deprecated **(Although it works fine on xCode and Android simulators but it doesn't work when i release the app.)**

My second attempt was to attach the didfocus event listener on the parent stack componentDidMount like below:

```
this.refs.stackNavigator.navigationContext.addListener('didfocus',(event) => { // Some code here calling an action });
```

But also didn't work as i found somewhere someone was saying that attaching the listener should be before rendering the navigator and suggested attaching the listener to the `renderScene` function of the navigator. **(Also, all works fine on simulators, but not on released apps.)**

My third attempt was to actually do that using the `renderScene` method and also same result as the above two attempts, all works fine on simulators but in release, nothing works. **(Also, all works fine on simulators, but not on released apps.)**

Any help or if anyone encountered such behavior, i would highly appreciate his feedback.

Thanks community!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `react-native-scrollable-tab-view`? You can use onChangeTab:

```
<ScrollableTabView onChangeTab={this.onChangeTab} />
```

and I'm pretty sure you can set up the method like this:

```
onChangeTab({i, ref, from }) {
  this.children[i].onFocus();
}
```

You have to set each tab with a `ref={(ref) => (this.children[i] = ref)}` where `i` is the index of the tab. Now you can create an onFocus() method in your tab and it should call it when that tab is selected.

Comment: I believe you also need to pass an `i={ i }` prop to each tab too. Where `i` is the index of the tab.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Matt. Yes i am using `react-native-scrollable-tab-view` but inside each tab, there is a navigator.

`<tabOne>
<Navigator>
</tabOne>

<tabTwo>
<Navigator>
</tabTwo>

<tabThree>
<Navigator>
</tabThree>`

My issue is in this child navigator not on the tab level.
On some specific scenes in the first navigator, i want to hide the bottom navigation.
I'm not really sure if your way would help. You think?